# Stuck in wampserver: it is in yellow mode

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

Yesterday I added some pathfile in an environmental variable, and now I am unable to run wampserver. I have deleted some path. Now I am totally confuesed. My localhost is still not working.

Below I show the path I added to my environment variable. How should I edit that to get wampserver working again?

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
```

Comment: Uninstall,delete folder,reinstall.Backup your www folder.

Comment: Without knowing what service refuses to work, you can't fix it... Check the error logs of mysql, php and apache. If one of them contains an error when you start WAMP, google that error and add them to your question if you need additional help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix your problem:

1. Please first remove that include path file.
2. If you are using Skype, then please change the port number or close that port (options=>connections=>Port Enable/Disable).
3. Please also check other services like IIS, or other similar services which could lead to your WAMP sticking.
4. Please check, after restarting the WAMP server, that it is working.
5. If it's still not working, then reinstall the WAMP or replace the file which you have included the path.