# How to solve Internal Server Error in Wamp

Tags: apache, wamp

I'm not able to launch localhost. When we click on wamp (green color ) -->localhost it shows the following:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

### Apache Error Log File

```
signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Sep 23 00:10:23.203125 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 520:tid 1816] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Sep 23 13:13:02.578125 2013] [core:warn] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00098: pid file D:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Sep 23 13:13:04.984375 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 23 13:13:04.984375 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Mon Sep 23 13:13:04.984375 2013] [core:notice] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Mon Sep 23 13:13:05.687500 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3824
[Mon Sep 23 13:13:17.562500 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3824:tid 1816] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Sep 23 13:58:48.343750 2013] [core:error] [pid 3824:tid 624] [client 127.0.0.1:1462] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 23 13:59:01.687500 2013] [core:error] [pid 3824:tid 624] [client 127.0.0.1:1464] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 23 13:59:22.375000 2013] [core:error] [pid 3824:tid 624] [client 127.0.0.1:1465] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 23 13:59:46.781250 2013] [core:error] [pid 3824:tid 624] [client 127.0.0.1:1466] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 23 13:59:58.640625 2013] [core:error] [pid 3824:tid 624] [client 127.0.0.1:1467] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:03.062500 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:06.375000 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3824:tid 1816] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:08.671875 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2920:tid 268] AH00430: Parent: Child process 3824 exited successfully.
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:24.453125 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1768:tid 336] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:24.453125 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1768:tid 336] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:24.453125 2013] [core:notice] [pid 1768:tid 336] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:24.484375 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1768:tid 336] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2616
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:25.718750 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2616:tid 1816] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Sep 23 14:04:51.593750 2013] [core:error] [pid 2616:tid 612] [client 127.0.0.1:1561] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Sep 23 14:05:00.015625 2013] [core:error] [pid 2616:tid 612] [client 127.0.0.1:1562] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

The error that happened is a tremendous one. Until yesterday it was working very well.
How do I solve this error?

Comment: did you add any rewriting rules recently?

Comment: Please check my below post link:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18638413/2293428

Comment: i didn't add any rewriting rules recently

Comment: 1.How to remove path file

Comment: Hello Guys now it is working properly after uninstalling Skype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to uninstall SKYPE, it can be configured to stop it using ports 80 and 443 ( the webserver standard ports )

**How to Configure SKYPE so it does not require port 80 or 443**

Run SKYPE
then using the menus do this:

Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection

Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections'

Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

If you are running Windows 8 SKYPE comes as an app and this cannot ( as yet ) be configured in this way.
However if you uninstall the SKYPE app and install SKYPE in the old way, you can reconfigure it, and it works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

500 Error can be occurred due to .htaccess file in your website directory. I had the problem. I remove the .htaccess file and use index.php for index page. I am talking about the codeigniter. If this happen, don't forget to check the .htaccess file and configuration file. That's all I had, now problem solved.