# Wampserver doesen't open the pages directly anymone

Tags: localhost, wampserver

After installing the new version of wampserer, wich i find horrible, a have some problem when opening my project

Let's say I have a folder called website under wamp/www/
when i click on my folder on the wampserver localhost page, instead of directing me this link *http://localhost:8080/website/* I am directed to this one *website/*

The software do work, but i have to open my files manually in the adress bar... Is there some way to avoid that ?

Comment: Also why have you changed the port number Apache is listening on to 8080. All the links on the WAMPServer homepage assume you are using the default port 80

Comment: true, it's duplacate.... by the way, I changed settings to port 8080 so i could use programs like skype who work on 80. This way no need to close them

Comment: Not necessary, see this post for [how to configure skype not to use port 80 and 443](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955098/how-to-solve-internal-server-error-in-wamp/18958714#18958714)